# Create Dynamic array for google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

I am currently trying to generate a line chart using Google charts.
so i need to generate a dynamic array of date and the value as given below

```
 data.addColumn('date', 'Time of Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Rating');

 data.addRows([
      [new Date(2015, 0, 1),5],  [new Date(2015, 0, 2), 7],  [new Date(2015, 0, 3), 3]
      ]);
```

I try to create an array

> [[new Date(2015, 0, 1),5],  [new Date(2015, 0, 2), 7],  [new
>   Date(2015, 0, 3), 3]]

```
for(var i=1; i<=10 ;i++){ 
    var last = new Date(date.getTime() - (i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var day =last.getDate();
    var month=last.getMonth()+1;
    var year=last.getFullYear();
    row[i]=[]
    row[i][0] = new Date(year,month,day);
    row[i][1]=5;

    }
data.addRows(row);
```

It show and error in in fireBug

> Every row given must be either null or an array.

Sorry I am new in JS.please help me to do. Is any problem in generating array or any other ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of using `addRows`, use `addRow`

then just feed the array directly

`data.addRow([new Date(year,month,day), i]);`

see following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    // create data table
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Time of Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Rating');

    // load data table
    var date = new Date();
    for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
      var last = new Date(date.getTime() - (i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var day = last.getDate();
      var month = last.getMonth()+1;
      var year = last.getFullYear();
      data.addRow([new Date(year,month,day), i]);
    }

    var chart = new  google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('barChart'));
    chart.draw(data, {
      title: 'My Bar chart',
      is3D: 'true'
    });
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barChart"></div>
```